# Minecraft Pi Edition display nothing on Arch Linux ARM

Tags: archlinux, minecraft

On Arch, running MC Pi would get an error, say it can't find the two files libpng12.so.0 and libSDL-1.2.so.0.

So, I used the following commands...

```
sudo pacman -S sdl
yaourt -S libpng12
```

...to install the libraries.

Then I got another error "failed to open vchiq instance", and I found a solution at there: 
http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=7104&start=25

Finally, it just opened a black window:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Tf6F.png

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure exactly how you performed the installation process, but take a look at [this tutorial](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-minecraft-on-raspberry-pi/) (for both Raspbian and Arch Linux):

> 1. Start the graphical interface:
>
>    ```
>    $ startx
>    ```
> 2. Download Minecraft:
>
>    ```
>    $ wget -c https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.minecraft.net/pi/minecraft-pi-0.1.1.tar.gz
>    ```
> 3. Extract the archive and cd into the extracted directory:
>
>    ```
>    $ tar -zxvf minecraft-pi-0.1.1.tar.gz <br>
>    $ cd mcpi
>    ```
> 4. Run Minecraft on your Raspberry Pi:
>
>    ```
>    $ ./minecraft-pi
>    ```

Comment: I downloaded the image file from http://archlinuxarm.org/ and use "dd" to write it into my sdcard.The game running process is the same as you written above

Comment: Try to compile it yourself with these steps and see if you can get it to work.

Comment: Do you mean compile Arch myself ? I don't know how to do this.

Comment: I edited the question.  Follow the instructions from the as closely as possible.